# Evaluate button text in statement

Tags: javascript, button, text

Hi I was trying to evaluate the button's textContent in a statement but really nothing happens.

My HTML:

```
<div class="app">
    <h2 id="question"></h2>
    <button class="options" type="button" value="val"><span></span></button>
    <button class="options" type="button" value="val"><span></span></button>
    <button class="options" type="button" value="val"><span></span></button>
    <button class="options" type="button" value="val"><span></span></button>
    </br>
    <button id="submit" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
    <button id="back" type="button" name="button">Back</button>
</div>

function evaluate() {
    // click the submit button
    submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        //check if the selected answer is correct
        for(i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            if(options[i].classList.contains('picked').textContent === 6) {
                alert('welldone')
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: Make sure you properly declare your variables `for(i = 0;` should be `for(var i = 0;` or `for(let i = 0;`.

Comment: as well as your HTML, we need to know how you are defining `options`. (The problem is likely to be that `options` has length `0` - ie. that you have tried to select elements that don't actually exist on the page.)

Comment: Oh, and another problem - `.textContent` will return a *string*, bu you're doing an `===` (strict equality) check with the *number* value `6`. You should change so you're comparing to the string `'6'`

Comment: options is defined:
var options = document.querySelectorAll('.options');

Comment: Just realised another serious problem `contains` returns a Boolean value, which has no `textContent` attribute. (Rather annoyingly, the code won't throw an error, you'll just be comparing `undefined` to `6` or whatever value you really have there). I think you want the `if` statement to be `if(options[i].classList.contains('picked') && options[i].textContent === 6)`

Comment: ye it makes more sense I changed it to your suggestion, but this won't solve the problem ofc

Answer (score 1):

If you trying to compare button text and class at the same time you can use below code. Please note you are using `===` which will compare the data type as well so either change your `6` to `'6'` or change your comparison operator from `===` to `==`. Check this link for details regarding [Comparison Operators](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp)

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit");
        submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
            //check if the selected answer is correct
            var options = document.querySelectorAll('.options');
            for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
                if (options[i].classList.contains('picked') && options[i].textContent === "6") {
                    alert('welldone')
                }
            }
        });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">
    <h2 id="question"></h2>
    <button class="options picked" type="button" value="val"><span>6</span></button>
    <button class="options" type="button" value="val"><span></span></button>
    <button class="options" type="button" value="val"><span></span></button>
    <button class="options" type="button" value="val"><span></span></button>
    </br>
    <button id="submit" type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
    <button id="back" type="button" name="button">Back</button>
</div>
```